# Protocol Conformance Error in UITest Project

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a very weird error in my UITest project in Swift.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "protocol conformance descriptor for IntroductionToMocking.User : Swift.Decodable in IntroductionToMocking", referenced from:
      lazy protocol witness table accessor for type IntroductionToMocking.User and conformance IntroductionToMocking.User : Swift.Decodable in IntroductionToMocking in MockHTTPClient.o
  "protocol descriptor for IntroductionToMocking.HTTPClientProtocol", referenced from:
      protocol conformance descriptor for IntroductionToMockingUITests.MockHTTPClient : IntroductionToMocking.HTTPClientProtocol in IntroductionToMockingUITests in MockHTTPClient.o
  "type metadata for IntroductionToMocking.User", referenced from:
      IntroductionToMockingUITests.MockHTTPClient.authenticate(username: Swift.String, password: Swift.String, completion: (IntroductionToMocking.User?) -> ()) -> () in MockHTTPClient.o
      lazy protocol witness table accessor for type IntroductionToMocking.User and conformance IntroductionToMocking.User : Swift.Decodable in IntroductionToMocking in MockHTTPClient.o
```

In my UITest project I created the MockHTTPClient which uses the HTTPClientProtocol as shown below:

```
import Foundation
@testable import IntroductionToMocking

class MockHTTPClient: HTTPClientProtocol {

    func authenticate(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (User?) -> Void) {


        guard let url = Bundle(for: MockHTTPClient.self).url(forResource: "auth-success-response", withExtension: "json"),
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                return completion(nil)
        }

        let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
        completion(user)
    }

}
```

The protocol is defined in the main project as follows:

```
import Foundation

protocol HTTPClientProtocol {
    func authenticate(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (User?) -> Void )
}
```

I cannot figure out what is going on and why I am getting the error. Any ideas?

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler Yes I have already imported that.

Comment: I'm seeing the same 3 errors in Xcode 12 for a project that compiled fine in Xcode 11! Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @AshleyMills did you solve the issue?

Comment: Maybe one of your models conforms to _Identifiable_ and you are running with iOS <13.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue is related with universal Apps. I was getting the same error mentioned in the question.
The work around mentioned here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/654309 worked for me. It's not ideal but adding the files to the test target got the tests compiling and running.

The workaround is to add the files also to test target.
It appears to be an error related to the synthesised code during compilation

For example in my compilation error when running the tests I see this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "nominal type descriptor for MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig", referenced from:
      _symbolic _____y_____G 9Tests_iOS35SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceC 12MyApp014SMPSmallWidgetD0V in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
      _symbolic _____y______ySay_____G_____GSo17OS_dispatch_queueCG 7Combine10PublishersO11SubscribeOnV AA12AnyPublisherV 12MyApp20SMPSmallWidgetConfigV s5NeverO in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
      _symbolic _____y______y______ySay_____G_____GSo17OS_dispatch_queueCGAIG 7Combine10PublishersO9ReceiveOnV AC09SubscribeD0V AA12AnyPublisherV 12MyApp20SMPSmallWidgetConfigV s5NeverO in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
      _symbolic Say_____GSg 12MyApp20SMPSmallWidgetConfigV in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
      _symbolic _____ySay_____G_____G 7Combine12AnyPublisherV 12MyApp20SMPSmallWidgetConfigV s5NeverO in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
      _symbolic Say_____GSgz_Xx 12MyApp20SMPSmallWidgetConfigV in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
      _symbolic Say_____GIegg_ 12MyApp20SMPSmallWidgetConfigV in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
      ...
  "protocol conformance descriptor for MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig : Swift.Equatable in MyApp", referenced from:
      lazy protocol witness table accessor for type MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig and conformance MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig : Swift.Equatable in MyApp in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
  "protocol conformance descriptor for MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig : Swift.Encodable in MyApp", referenced from:
      lazy protocol witness table accessor for type MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig and conformance MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig : Swift.Encodable in MyApp in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
  "type metadata for MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig", referenced from:
      lazy protocol witness table accessor for type MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig and conformance MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig : Swift.Encodable in MyApp in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
      lazy protocol witness table accessor for type MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig and conformance MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig : Swift.Equatable in MyApp in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
  "static MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig.defaultSMPSmallWidgetConfig() -> MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig", referenced from:
      Tests_iOS.SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.(givenSmallConfig in _F12F8146E6B85CC300C4FE7EE03F2059)() -> MyApp.SMPSmallWidgetConfig in SMPWidgetsConfigDefaultsPersistenceTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Adding `SMPSmallWidgetConfig` to the tests target solves the compilation issue.
This is of course in addition to having the
`@testable import MyApp` in the tests

Comment: I added details about the workaround in my response. I hope it helps @matt